# Mongoose find() with cursor vs findOne() performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am getting unexpectadly long query time for findOne() mongoose queries when compared to find()

```
var batchSize = 25;
var cursor = collection1.find().lean().cursor({batchSize: batchSize});
cursor.on('data', function(col1rec){
    var parm1 = col1rec.parm1;
    var parm2 = col1rec.parm2;
    collection2.findOne({parm1:parm1}, function(err, col2rec){
        collection3.findOne({parm2:parm2}, function(err, col3rec){
            var linkRec = Object.assign({}, col1rec, col2rec, col3red);
            new Collection4(linkRec).save();
        });
    });
});
```

**Use case**: link records from different collections.

1. get a cursor on collection1 to loop over;
2. query collection2 and find doc with parm1.
3. query collection3 and find doc with parm2.
4. save linked record to mongoDB collection4.

collection2 has parm1 has index and Collection3 has parm2 has index.

To monitor the database avg query times I used [mongotop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongotop/). which produces the following outputs:

```
         ns    total    read    write    2017-11-29T17:12:50Z
Collection3     56ms    56ms      0ms
Collection4     56ms     0ms     56ms
Collection2     54ms    54ms      0ms
Collection1      2ms     2ms      0ms
```

**How can findOne in Collection2 and Collection3 take ~50 ms as in Collection1 a cursor iterating take only 2ms?**

**This really adds up and in the end I get really long processing time. What am I doing wrong and how can I lower the findOne query time?**

Also, if instead of nesting the findOne in a cursor and loop over the collection, if I try to link just 1 record by a parameter the findOne take ~1 ms.

**Is it not a good policy to have nested mongoose queries inside the cursor?**

Comment: Two things that I can think of here is a) other processes running queries against collection2 and collection3 which also get captured by mongotop and b) perhaps the number of documents in the collections justifies the different times?

Comment: @dnickless Collection1 is significantly larger then any other collection.

Comment: By size or by number of documents? Or both?

Comment: @dnickless Both.

Comment: How often did you run your performance tests? Against a warm or cold MongoDB instance? Perhaps collection1 was entirely cached and the rest hadn't been touched yet? Do you get the same numbers when running it a couple of times?

Comment: I am still doing different tests. It looks like the larger the batchSize the smaller the times.